# Haskell filter operation with modulo

Tags: haskell, modulo

I'm trying to use the "filter" from Haskell but I've got stuck.
I wanna use the filter and modulo together in one function like this

```
multipleOf7 :: [Int] -> [Int]
multipleOf7 x = filter (test) x 
   where test = x mod 7 == 0
```

I also tried to use the `mod` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have written mod using backquote

```
x `mod` 7 == 0
```

or use it normally

```
mod x 7 == 0
```

In haskell you can use any function as infix.
If you define a simple function like

```
myFunction x y = x * y
```

then if you want you can use it like:

```
z = 40 `myFunction` 50
```

if you want you can also define function with an infix style.

```
x `myFunction` y = x * y
```

that would be strictly the same, and you would still be able to call it the other way also:

```
z = myFunction 40 50
```

---

Moreover, in the same spirit, you can easily define custom infix operators/symbols in Haskell. For example:

```
(-!!->) a b = (a,b)
-- or identically, but no need for backticks for infix operators
a -!!-> b = (a,b)
```

that can be used this way:

```
c = 1 -!!-> 2
-- and now c == (1,2)
```

but this should be used sparingly, choose your custom symbol carefully, and with the clear intent of readability IMHO.

Comment: Oh man, thanks!
i knew the problem is just a little thing but I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 2):

What you have to understand is that Haskell has a "very" uniform syntax (not that much "special" cases). You call a function `f` with arguments `x y` with `f x y`. Now `mod` is just an ordinary function like all other functions. So you should call it with:

```
mod x 7
```

You can also use backtics to call a binary operator with the function in between like:

```
x `mod` 7
```

So you can fix the problem with:

```
multipleOf7 :: [Int] -> [Int]
multipleOf7 x = filter (test) x
   where test x = mod x 7 == 0
```

or more cleaner:

```
multipleOf7 :: [Int] -> [Int]
multipleOf7 = filter test
   where test x = mod x 7 == 0
```

You can also rewrite the `test` function such that:

```
test = (0 ==) . flip mod 7
```

or make a shorter filter like:

```
multipleOf7 :: Integral b => [b] -> [b]
multipleOf7 = filter ((0 ==) . flip mod 7)
```

*(opinion)* In my personal opinion it is indeed weird at first to see `mod x 7`. But after a while you start to find this useful since it saves a lot of brain cycles not taking complicated syntax/grammar rules into account.

Answer (score 1):

Since `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` and in your case *a = Int*,

```
multipleOf7 :: [Int] -> [Int]
multipleOf7 ns = filter f ns
  where
    f :: Int -> Bool
    f i = i `mod` 7 == 0
```

Like Willem Van Onsem, I would probably [loosen the *Int* into an *Integral a => a*](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html), since the library function `mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a` is just as general. I would also parameterize the *7* into an *n*, [ditch the *ns*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) and write the *f* as a lambda:

```
multipleOf :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
multipleOf n = filter (\i -> i `mod` n == 0)
```

Willem Van Onsem then rewrites it into [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree):

```
multipleOf7 :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
multipleOf7 = filter ((0 ==) . flip mod 7)
```

Pointfree style is sometimes more readable. I'd argue that this isn't the case here. Another variation is available here,

```
multipleOf :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
multipleOf n = filter ((== 0) . (`mod` n))
```

Still, I like the first versions with `where` or a lambda better.